# Collapsing toolbar layout status bar issue

Tags: android, material-design, statusbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

i don't know why, but seems that when the toolbar collapse, appears a second status bar.

I used `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in all components, because without this the toolbar came out from the status bar.

Here are some images to better explain:
[Images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3eyDGRs7OssQzVvVktXNVJTY0U)

I have never seen such a thing, and I tried them all but I do not know how to solve it.
I could not find anything on the net.

Here the code:

Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_actor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_protection" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/webview_bio"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Activity onCreate:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    if(collapsingToolbarLayout!=null){
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(advm.getName());
    }
```

Styles: (the one I use in the current Activity is the second)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems an extra-padding added by CollapsingToolbarLayout on its fitSystemWindows().
I think you have to enable `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` too at theme level (API19+), to get a stable layout as it was in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever faces this issue, add this to parent elements:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

In above code I think it will be :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
...
>
...
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Good luck,'.